# Выбрать максимальное значение mysql

Tags: mysql, max

```
CREATE TABLE `incoming` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt_first` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_second` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

необходимо выбрать id максимального значение между разницой дат:

```
MAX(unix_timestamp(dt_first)-unix_timestamp(dt_second))
```

Comment: А если записей с одинаковой максимальной разностью - несколько? Ну и точная версия MySQL - она какая?

Comment: Если несколько, то можно взять любмую. Кстати, по какому принципу тогда идет сортировка, если значения одинаковые, автоматически идет сортировка по 2му параметру prikey, в моем случае id?

Comment: *по какому принципу тогда идет сортировка, если значения одинаковые* По принципу "а как получится". Ну или "а фиг знает"... А вот на какую-то "автоматическую" сортировку не рассчитывайте - серверу это вообще не упёрлось, он делает только то, что сказано, и дурной инициативы не проявляет.

Comment: PS. А нафига Вам два одинаковых индекса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM incoming
ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, dt_first, dt_second) DESC
LIMIT 1
```